# Display leaflet map coordinates in Django template from WKB POINT field in PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, leaflet, point

I'm new to all things GEO. I have a WKB POINT field in a PostgreSQL database that stores locations. I also have a leaflet map on my Django template with hard coded lat and long added, which shows a working map on my front end.

POINT example:
`0101000020E610000051954507C62C1FC0144708B9E6784840`

Can someone advise how I can decode the point field and insert the lat and long into my template so the map will update to the correct location from the database?

If you need anything else like models just let me know. Any help appreciated.

**Template.html**

```
    <div style="padding-top: 280px">
    <h3 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Location</h3>
     <script>
      function map_init_basic (map, options) {
        
          L.marker([11.5, 20.5]).addTo(map);
          map.panTo(new L.LatLng(11.737, 20.923));
        
      }
     </script>

{% leaflet_map "mymap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
```

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the latitude and longitude to your template and conduct the WKB decoding in your views if your data is stored in a PostgreSQL database and you have a Django model representing it.

your models.py file should have this code

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

    class YourModel(models.Model):
        location = models.PointField()
```

views.py file should have this code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

def your_view(request):
    # Assuming you have a queryset that retrieves the data from your database
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()

    # Extracting latitude and longitude from the POINT field
    location_data = []
    for instance in queryset:
        # Decode WKB and extract coordinates
        point = GEOSGeometry(instance.location.wkb)
        lat, lon = point.y, point.x

        # Append latitude and longitude to the location_data list
        location_data.append({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})

    context = {'location_data': location_data}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

You can now use the extracted latitude and longitude by updating the JavaScript code in your_template.html.

Here is updated code of your template.html file

```
<div style="padding-top: 280px">
    <h3 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Location</h3>
    <script>
        function map_init_basic(map, options) {
            {% for location in location_data %}
                L.marker([{{ location.lat }}, {{ location.lon }}]).addTo(map);
            {% endfor %}
            
            // You may want to adjust the center based on your data
            map.panTo(new L.LatLng({{ location_data.0.lat }}, {{ location_data.0.lon }}));
        }
    </script>

    {% leaflet_map "mymap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
</div>
```

Hope it works :)